# MTA questions about POSTFIX, outlook,,smtp, pop, etc

Tags: mail, postfix, smtp

So this is a pretty noob question.  I have a linux server that rocks postfix.  We've been using it as our MTA for years.  There are a few computers that run outook, one thunderbird, and a bunch of cell phones.  My question is:  Is there a way to set up POSTFIX, or another linux MTA, that supports syncing?  That way the read, sent, received mails on all devices will be synced appropriately to the server? Is it possible?  When I worked for a big corp, this is the setup we had through windows and outlook, but I want it linux style.

Thanks,
P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access your email mailbox(es) using [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imap) protocol.

You may consider using [Dovecot](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/#Generic_information_about_mail_servers) IMAP server.
http://wiki2.dovecot.org/PrebuiltBinaries#Ubuntu
http://wiki2.dovecot.org/LDA/Postfix

Comment: Have to give my approval of Dovecot for IMAP and POP3 accounts - integrates easily with Postfix and there is abundant documentation on getting Postfix and Dovecot working together.

Comment: neato!  Thanks a lot.  I'll see if I can learn this IMAP business through Dovecot and Postfix!